# How to reverse a number/string in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have used this code to reverse a number but it is not working.

```
var buffer = new Buffer("<inputNumber>", "ucs2");
Array.prototype.reverse.call(new Unit16Array(buffer));
return buffer.toString("ucs2");
```

Where was I wrong? Is this approach right? Any other way of reversing a number/string without using buffer?

Comment: `str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Comment: I have used this already but it says `.split() is not a function`

Comment: `str` should be string

Comment: @vsvk you have to split by empty string, you need quotes in the parenthesis, like that `.split('')`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to convert number to string :

```
String literal -> str = "" + num + "";
String constructor -> str = String(num);
toString -> str = num.toString();
String Literal simple -> str = "" + num;
```

The **split()** method is used to split a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```
Code : console.log('1000'.split(""));
Output : ["1", "0", "0", "0"]
```

The **reverse()** method is used to reverse an array in place. The first array element becomes the last and the last becomes the first.

```
Code : console.log(["1", "0", "0", "0"].reverse());
Output : ["0", "0", "0", "1"]
```

The **join()** method is used to join all elements of an array into a string.

```
Code : console.log(["1", "0", "0", "0"].reverse().join(""));
Output : "0001"
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a number first you have to convert it into string. Convert that string into array. Reverse the array and join it to make a string then parse that string to number

```
var num = 1543;
var reverseNum = parseInt(a.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
//Output : 3451
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is for numbers, it does also ask about strings, and was Google's first answer.

```
function reverse(value) {  
  return Array.from(
    String(value || '')
  ).reverse().join('')
}
```

> [**Be careful of using string.split('')**](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/reverse-a-string-in-javascript-or-node-js) to split the given string into its characters. The String#split method doesn’t handle UTF-16 characters like emojis. The list of characters would then lose the emojis as individual characters. That’s the reason we recommend using Array.from() to create an array of characters from a given string.